# TypeScript doesn't convert class members (other classes) correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I came across a problem that I cannot solve. The rest response returns the following object:

```
[{
  "username": "ljkkljk",
  "hotelRoles": [
    {
      "hotelId": "lkjkj",
      "role": {
        "code": "ROLE_USER",
        "name": "User administration"
      }
    },
    {
      "hotelId": "ljkklj",
      "role": {
        "code": "ROLE_USER",
        "name": "User administration"
      }
  }],
  "applications": [],
  "enabled": false,
  "title": null,
  "email": "lkj.lj@lkj.lkj",
  "firstName": "ljk",
  "lastName": "lkj",
  "middleName": null,
  "dateOfBirth": null,
  "telephone": null,
  "mobile": "+ljkl",
  "job": null,
  "department": null,
  "companyName": "ljkl",
  "employeeId": null,
  "taxId": null,
  "cashRegister": null,
  "address1": null,
  "address2": null,
  "townCity": null,
  "regionState": null,
  "postCode": null,
  "country": "ljkl",
  "website": null,
  "fullName": "jklkljkli"
}]
```

I try to map it with the current TypeScript class structure:

**UserManagementData.ts**

```
export class UsersManagementData {

  private username: string;
  private hotelRoles: HotelRole[];
  private title: string;
  private email: string;
  private firstName: string;
  private lastName: string;
  private middleName: string;
  private dateOfBirth: string;
  private telephone: string;
  private mobile: string;
  private job: string;
  private department: string;
  private companyName: string;
  private employeeId: string;
  private taxId: string;
  private cashRegister: string;
  private address1: string;
  private address2: string;
  private townCity: string;
  private regionState: string;
  private postCode: string;
  private country: string;
  private website: string;
  private fullName: string;

  constructor(usersManagementData: any = DEFAULT_VALUES) {
    Object.assign(this, usersManagementData);
  }

  get _username(): string {
    return this.username;
  }

  set _username(value: string) {
    this.username = value;
  }

  get _hotelRoles(): HotelRole[] {
    return this.hotelRoles;
  }

  set _hotelRoles(value: HotelRole[]) {
    this.hotelRoles = value;
  }

  get _title(): string {
    return this.title;
  }

  set _title(value: string) {
    this.title = value;
  }

  get _email(): string {
    return this.email;
  }

  set _email(value: string) {
    this.email = value;
  }

  get _firstName(): string {
    return this.firstName;
  }

  set _firstName(value: string) {
    this.firstName = value;
  }

  get _lastName(): string {
    return this.lastName;
  }

  set _lastName(value: string) {
    this.lastName = value;
  }

  get _middleName(): string {
    return this.middleName;
  }

  set _middleName(value: string) {
    this.middleName = value;
  }

  get _dateOfBirth(): string {
    return this.dateOfBirth;
  }

  set _dateOfBirth(value: string) {
    this.dateOfBirth = value;
  }

  get _telephone(): string {
    return this.telephone;
  }

  set _telephone(value: string) {
    this.telephone = value;
  }

  get _mobile(): string {
    return this.mobile;
  }

  set _mobile(value: string) {
    this.mobile = value;
  }

  get _job(): string {
    return this.job;
  }

  set _job(value: string) {
    this.job = value;
  }

  get _department(): string {
    return this.department;
  }

  set _department(value: string) {
    this.department = value;
  }

  get _companyName(): string {
    return this.companyName;
  }

  set _companyName(value: string) {
    this.companyName = value;
  }

  get _employeeId(): string {
    return this.employeeId;
  }

  set _employeeId(value: string) {
    this.employeeId = value;
  }

  get _taxId(): string {
    return this.taxId;
  }

  set _taxId(value: string) {
    this.taxId = value;
  }

  get _cashRegister(): string {
    return this.cashRegister;
  }

  set _cashRegister(value: string) {
    this.cashRegister = value;
  }

  get _address1(): string {
    return this.address1;
  }

  set _address1(value: string) {
    this.address1 = value;
  }

  get _address2(): string {
    return this.address2;
  }

  set _address2(value: string) {
    this.address2 = value;
  }

  get _townCity(): string {
    return this.townCity;
  }

  set _townCity(value: string) {
    this.townCity = value;
  }

  get _regionState(): string {
    return this.regionState;
  }

  set _regionState(value: string) {
    this.regionState = value;
  }

  get _postCode(): string {
    return this.postCode;
  }

  set _postCode(value: string) {
    this.postCode = value;
  }

  get _country(): string {
    return this.country;
  }

  set _country(value: string) {
    this.country = value;
  }

  get _website(): string {
    return this.website;
  }

  set _website(value: string) {
    this.website = value;
  }

  get _fullName(): string {
    return this.fullName;
  }

  set _fullName(value: string) {
    this.fullName = value;
  }
}

const DEFAULT_VALUES = {
  username: null,
  hotelRoles: null,
  title: null,
  email: null,
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  middleName: null,
  dateOfBirth: null,
  telephone: null,
  mobile: null,
  job: null,
  department: null,
  companyName: null,
  employeeId: null,
  taxId: null,
  cashRegister: null,
  address1: null,
  address2: null,
  townCity: null,
  regionState: null,
  postCode: null,
  country: null,
  website: null,
  fullName: null
};
```

**HotelRole.ts**

```
export class HotelRole {

  private hotelId: string;
  private role: Role[];

  constructor(hotelRole: any = DEFAULT_VALUES) {
    Object.assign(this, hotelRole);
  }

  get _hotelId(): string {
    return this.hotelId;
  }

  set _hotelId(value: string) {
    this.hotelId = value;
  }

  get _role(): Role[] {
    return this.role;
  }

  set _role(value: Role[]) {
    this.role = value;
  }
}

const DEFAULT_VALUES = {
  hotelId: null,
  role: null
};
```

and lastly the **Role.ts**

```
export class Role {

 private code: string;
 private name: string;

 constructor(role: any = DEFAULT_VALUES) {
   Object.assign(this, role);
 }

  get _code(): string {
    return this.code;
  }

  set _code(value: string) {
    this.code = value;
  }

  get _name(): string {
    return this.name;
  }

  set _name(value: string) {
    this.name = value;
  }
}

const DEFAULT_VALUES = {
  code: null,
  name: null
};
```

The first parent object (**UserManagementData.ts**) maps correctly, but **HotelRoles.ts** and **Roles.ts** do not map. They are mapped is simple JS objects.

What am I doing wrong. I think I've done this before a million times and never had such problems. Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that they are simple JS Objects? Your initialization code is probably more important than what you've shared here.

Also on an unrelated note, I have mixed feelings on this pattern in general. The `Object.assign` call seems like it could be really destructive.

Comment: Remove those getters/setters . They are not neccessary here. And `null` as a default value makes no sense either IMO.

Comment: @JonasW. why not necessary?

Comment: Just make the properties `public`.

Comment: @Harangue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958742/typescript-class-with-a-constructor-which-calls-methods-depending-incoming-para this is concerning the Object.assign(). How do I know, because the getters are no populated and this object doesn't show a type in chrome console during service log output.

Comment: Do you need this classes for something (e.g. do you need methods?) And is the rest response always the same?

Comment: Yes I need these methods and classes. I do not want to do it the JS way, but the TS way with getters/setters. About the rest response you mean the structure or the content? The structure is always the same.

Comment: `but the TS way`, thats not ts, thats ugly. Thats kind of java

Comment: I am coming from java. :)

Comment: Okay. Just forget every "best practice" you learned already. Getters and setters arent always useful. If they are like `set property(value){ this._property = value }` you should simply make the property public. If you then somewhen decide that a getter/setter might be useful, you can replace the getter/setter with a property without the need to refactor.

Comment: @JonasW. thanks, I became a bit smarter now. Will def. use this approach in the next project. Too much is done in here to make the switch :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that using `Object.assign` does not turn the nested objects into instances of your class, you need to call the constructors manually:

```
export class UsersManagementData {

  constructor(usersManagementData: any) {
    Object.assign(this, usersManagementData);
    this.hotelRoles = usersManagementData.hotelRoles.map(hr => new HotelRole(hr));
  }
  ....
}

export class HotelRole {

  constructor(hotelRole: any) {
    Object.assign(this, hotelRole);
    this.role = new Role(hotelRole.role);
  }
}
```

**Note**

Your design is not very JS/TS oriented, if I had to guess I would say you come from a C#/Java background. I would recommend just converting the classes to interfaces if they have no other methods, (define the all the properties on the interfaces) and assign the JSON directly to a variable of the interface type:

```
export interface UsersManagementData {
  username: string;
  hotelRoles: HotelRole[];
  title: string;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  middleName: string;
  dateOfBirth: string;
  telephone: string;
  mobile: string;
  job: string;
  department: string;
  companyName: string;
  employeeId: string;
  taxId: string;
  cashRegister: string;
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  townCity: string;
  regionState: string;
  postCode: string;
  country: string;
  website: string;
  fullName: string;
}
export interface HotelRole {
  hotelId: string;
  role: Role[];
}

export interface Role {
  code: string;
  name: string;
}

let jsonResult: any; 
let umd : UsersManagementData = jsonResult;
```

Comment: Actually *note* is the real answer.

Comment: Does it mean I do not need to use `this.role = hotelRole.role.map(r=> new Role(r));` if I use the interface type for these objects? Is that done by TS itself?

Comment: @JonasW Yes, I would go with that 100% on the basis of the question that was asked, but there my be reasons for using classes if there are other methods on the class

Comment: @DenissM. With interfaces there is no constructor, so no place to put that code anyway, but you don't need it anyway. With interfaces you just describe the shape of your JSON object, how that object arrived to be of that shpe is not important for the TS compiler

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks. BTW `this.role = hotelRole.role.map(r=> new Role(r));` this gives a hotelRole.role.map is not a function. Is it prone to null objects?

Comment: @DenissM. wops, that should have been `roles`, that is the array of roles in your JSON from what I gathered. You should do null checking if you are going to go with that solution, I didn't do that in the demo code

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir nope that is `role` you had it correct. No `roles` in that object :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir with `Role` this doesn't work even if I do null checks and array length checks. Must be a more complex solution :(

Comment: um .. if `role` is an array it should work. Mabe it's not an array ? An then you would need `this.role = new Role(hotelRole.role)`. The basic idea should be the same .. you need to call the constructor of he class

Comment: had a second look at the JSON .. yes it's a simple object not an array

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir oops, my bad. You are correct :)